# prevent live chat Plugin to include inline javascript and cookie in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to dequeue inline JavaScript code from a live chat plugin in my website.

The live chat plugin inserts inline js (http://cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js) on my page without handler from a `TrackingCodeHelper` class, so I can't stop or dequeue this to include JS and add a COOKIE on my web page.

The reason behind that, I want to load Live chat plugin only when I have specific cookie on page.

I want to stop WordPress live chat plugin to insert JS and cookie on my page. it should be load only when browser have my custom cookie. We can dequeue add this plugin script through "addthis_widget" handler by this function in WordPress

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
function my_deregister_javascript() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'addthis_widget' );
}
```

but the live chat plugin doesn't give any handler to dequeue scripts. In the Live chat plugin it loads from this code `LiveChat::get_instance();`.

How can I stop that class from loading?

Comment: Can you add example of your code? Can you clarify exactly what you want to happen and what is happening? Also edit your tags, I don't see how PHP or WordPress are in any way relevant here. Also, this is a VERY broad question

Comment: i want to stop wordpress live chat plugin to insert JS ans cookie on my page.
it should be load only when browser have my custom cookie.

we can dequee add this plugin script through "addthis_widget" handler by this function in wordpres

`add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'addthis_widget' );
}`

but live chat plugin does't give any handler to dequee scripts.

in Live chat plugin its load from this code

`LiveChat::get_instance();`

how can i stop above class to load functionality

Comment: Comments don't help for that, your question would be a good place to add this :)